# Changing from transparent to colored status bar android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm working on Lollipop & I know how to color the status bar by setting this flag `FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS` & setting the color by 
`getWindow().setStatusBarColor(color);`

But I have a image & a transparent `ActionBar` & I want to show the image behind the action bar & when the users scrolls the `ListView` below the image the status bar should get fill with color as `ActionBar`

The problem is showing image behind the status bar & later after scrolling  filling status bar with color. I don't know how this effect can be achieved.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am interested in doing a similar thing..

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to add TranslucentActionBar Style on your style.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme.TranslucentActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar.Transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar.Transparent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
   <!--  <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item> -->
</style>
```

Add this method in your class.

```
@TargetApi(19) 
private void setTranslucentStatus(boolean on) {
    Window win = getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
    final int bits = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
    if (on) {
        winParams.flags |= bits;
    } else {
        winParams.flags &= ~bits;
    }
    win.setAttributes(winParams);
}
```

Next, Add this in OnCreate method before setContentView()

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            setTranslucentStatus(true);
        }
```

then status bar will be overlay your activity.

add scroll listener and add set status bar alpha method like this.

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.argb(alpha, 253, 152, 0));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it.

I'm unable to combine both coloring of status bar & also overlaying content behind it.

Comment: @Aky Did you add   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppTheme.TranslucentActionBar"  at AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I don't think using WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS & also setting status bar color would work together

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following flags to get the system bar transparent and draw over it:

```
activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
```

As explained here in method 1:
[Lollipop : draw behind statusBar with its color set to transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent)

After that, setting the system bar to transparent should do the trick (note that this is only available in API 21 or up):

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Then, for make the change when the screen scrolls, you need to use a scroll listener to switch between solid and transparent for the system bar with something like this:

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getPrimaryDarkkColor());
```

and

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

taking into account the scroll position in the listener.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy this code in your **onCreate** method and keep coding :)

**Code:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);


nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                if (scrollY > 50) {
                    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
                    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.rgb(85, 155, 247));
                } else {
                    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
                    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```