# android:fitsSystemWindows at runtime

Tags: android

My Android app starts with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity have an offset for status bar.

I want to remove this offset at runtime by clicking on the button. By clicking on the button I do the following, but it doesn't work, nothing happens:

```
findViewById(R.id.root).setFitsSystemWindows(false);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 20):

I have been dealing with this issue and found only this unanswered question.

Finally I've found the solution:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.root);
view.setFitsSystemWindows(false);
view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Setting fitsSystemWindows to true modifies the padding. Apparently disabling fitsSystemWindows keeps the padding set.

Comment: Man this was the response I've looking for! But what if I want to setFitsSystemWindows to true again?

Comment: You can set it again to true. Just remember to clear padding every time when setting to false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
```

Set Status flag to remove statusbar offset and Navigationbar to remove soft-buttons.

Comment: I already use this setting. I use android:windowTranslucentStatus and android:fitsSystemWindows. Both are true. And by clicking on the button I want to remove offset, but not remove translucent.

Comment: try this may be this answer could help.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28041425/3728591

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help me. The problem that I work in one activity. I don't can to recreate activity.