# Translucent status bar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am using the following layout (main_activity.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:text="@string/large_text" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

With the following styles-v21

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

But I still cannot archive a transparent status bar

**It look like this**

[image: Non-Transparent]

**But I want something like this** (New Google Newsstand App)

[image: Transparent status bar]

Note: I am using

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
```

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try this:

add this in your app theme:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Set `android:fitsSystemWindows=”true”` to root container

Now in your activity onCreate():

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
```

**Updated, Result:**

[image]

you can make the `snackbar` draw on top of screen:

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(parentLayout, str, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = snack.getView();
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
snack.show();
```

For more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746300/how-to-show-snackbar-at-top-of-the-screen/31746370)

Comment: I want to kiss you. Thanks so much, worked perfectly

Comment: take a look at this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354791/android-draw-behind-status-bar-but-not-behind-the-navigation-bar

Comment: I want this in only a single activity. How can i achieve ?

Answer (score 6):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Window window = getWindow();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); } }

}
```

Use this in your activity. But changing the status bar color is only allowed after android L

Comment: try removing the status bar color from the style you are using

Comment: removed, now its gray color, not transparent.

Comment: rafsanahmad0007's solution worked, thanks for all the help though.

Comment: Ok good for you..enjoy. This code will work too.i tested and seems fine

Comment: Thank you very match. This is the only answer worked for android 5.0

Answer (score 4):

The code below is making the status bar transparent but navigation bar opaque for API21+.

NOTE: you shouldn't be setting  `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      setupContentWindow()
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

fun setupContentWindow() {
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
}
```

Comment: This is perfect because it makes the status bar transparent but not the nav bar

Answer (score 1):

Add these two lines in the onCreate of the activity that you want its layout status bar to be transparent

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

No need to change your app theme or xml layout.  In doing this your bar doesn't have to be transparent throughout your whole app if you don't want to.

Comment: This is the correct answer. All other answers mistaken "transparent status bar" for "no status bar".

Comment: It should be like `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}` because `setStatusBarColor` requires minimum lollipop version

Answer (score 1):

It seems some people have grey status bar instead of transparent. To avoid this problem do the next in your activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    window.apply {
        clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Please remove this line from your CoordinatorLayout:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

**Edited,
Result:**

[image]

Comment: removed, now its gray color, but not transparent

Comment: getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Comment: use above lines in your activity.

Comment: I don't want it to be full screen, I want a transparent status bar, like the picture of (Play Newsstand) above