# Transparent white toolbar like new Gmail

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-toolbar, android-xml

In the new Gmail app, in the mail activity. The toolbar is white, and when you scroll down, the text appears under the toolbar (the toolbar is part transparent).

When I've tried to do this with alpha or color-code, the white becomes more greyish. While in Gmail, it's complete white.

How can I achieve such a design? Have anyone tried doing this before?

P.S: I'm trying to achieve this with a view, not a toolbar.

Edit: I'm talking about this entire space, toolbar+statusbar. It's complete white with opacity/transparency
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYD4M.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Translucent status bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313382/translucent-status-bar-in-android)

Comment: @barackos not the statusbar, the entire toolbar

Comment: I have achieved this one in a project. Tomorrow i can guide you on how to achieve it if you are interested.