# In Android How To Make Translucent Status Bar With Black Background Navigation Button

Tags: android, android-layout, statusbar, navigationbar

Guys I want to have translucent status bar with black background navigation buttons. Just like Netflix App as shown in picture. I tried really hard to find any way but I failed to achieve this. Any Idea?

[image]

Comment: Ok, what have you tried ? please post your code and your efforts

Comment: I tried this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42313556/8463520)

Answer (score 0):

Add in styles.xml in Base Application style

Change status bar color : `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/blackColor</item>`

For Translucent status bar : `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`

For navigation bar color : `<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/blackColor</item>`

in layout file use : `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in root layout.