# Transparent status bar (with visible navigation bar)

Tags: android, statusbar

I know this question has been asked many times, but all of the answers either not working, or use deprecated code:

- [Android Completely transparent Status Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar)
- [Transparent status bar - before Android 4.4 (KitKat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865621/transparent-status-bar-before-android-4-4-kitkat?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Lollipop : draw behind statusBar with its color set to transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent)

I want to achieve the same effect as latest google maps app:

[image]

- Fully transparent status bar (Only status bar. **not** navigation bar!)
- Non deprecated solution

`WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` partially working as it also hides the navigation bar also

Comment: Still looking for solution ? @dor506

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68506784/make-android-notification-bar-transparent-not-bottom-navigation-bar/68507065#68507065

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Step 1:** To make the status bar transparent: add the below into the style `themes.xml` or `sytles.xml`:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>

<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

**Step 2:** Then in activity to make the status bar overlaps with the activity:

The used window flags are deprecated as of API level 30, so they can be used till API level 29:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT in 21..29) { 
    window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
        SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE

} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
    window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    // Making status bar overlaps with the activity
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
}
```

**UPDATE For API-30**

> This doesn't actually make the status bar transparent, it makes it translucent and will still have a shadow to it

This is right on API-30, and reason because setting `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`.

Actually the `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` is only required on API level 19. If your app is greater than that, you can dismiss it at all.

Anyways, the way to fix this is to override the themes.xml/styles.xml in API-30; i.e. to have a `res\values-v30\themes.xml`; you can just add the main app theme like:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.TransparentStatusBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
     </style>
</resources>
```

**UPDATE 2 For API-30**

Just discovered a bug on API 30 that the bottom navigation overlaps with the activity obscuring the bottom part of it, that probably couldn't be discovered by the OP as they are using a map.

To solve this, [**As per documentation:**](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge?hl=fr#handle-overlaps)

> You can address overlaps by reacting to insets, which specify which
> parts of the screen intersect with system UI such as the navigation
> bar or the status bar. Intersecting can mean simply being displayed
> above the content, but it can also inform your app about system
> gestures, too.

So, we need to handle the System bars insets for API level 30+ to avoid your app overlapping with the navigation bar:

This requires the top root `ViewGroup` of the activity layout, and accordingly the `LayoutParams`  need to be coasted appropriately.

Here I am using a `ConstraintLayout` as a root layout, and `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`:

```
/*
*  Making the Navigation system bar not overlapping with the activity
*/
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {

    // Root ViewGroup of my activity
    val root = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.root)

    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(root) { view, windowInsets ->

        val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())

        // Apply the insets as a margin to the view. Here the system is setting
        // only the bottom, left, and right dimensions, but apply whichever insets are
        // appropriate to your layout. You can also update the view padding
        // if that's more appropriate.

        view.layoutParams =  (view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
            leftMargin = insets.left
            bottomMargin = insets.bottom
            rightMargin = insets.right
        }

        // Return CONSUMED if you don't want want the window insets to keep being
        // passed down to descendant views.
        WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
    }

}
```

This is tested on 8 devices/emulators on the range of API level 19 to API level 30.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually make the status bar transparent, it makes it translucent and will still have a shadow to it

Comment: @alfietap I updated the answer with the fix of this .. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: what about toolbar?

Comment: @user924 Which toolbar? the OP was asking about the status & navigation bars. You can hide the ActionBar from the activity's style.

Comment: @Zain anyway here's the correct and simple answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68488027/7767664 transparent toolbar can also be added and it will be under status bar

Answer (score 9):

To make the `StatusBar` completely transparent,

First, set its color as transparent in the theme or by code as :

```
//In Theme
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
//In Code
window.statusBarColor = android.R.color.transparent
```

Then, to draw the view behind the `StatusBar`, use this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
} else {
    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    )
}
```

You can also play with the `boolean` property `android:windowLightStatusBar`, it sets the `StatusBar`'s text and icon color as black or white, You can do it programmatically as well. You can also set color to your `NavigationBar` if you don't want to hide it.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your theme

```xml
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" ns1:targetApi="23">true</item>
```

And use this method

```kotlin
     private fun handleStatusBar() {
        //set fullScreen (draw under statusBar and NavigationBar )
            WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

            container.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { view, insets ->
            val navigationBarHeight = WindowInsetsCompat.toWindowInsetsCompat(insets)
                .getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars()).bottom

            view.updatePadding(bottom = navigationBarHeight)
            WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED.toWindowInsets()
        }

        //make statusBar content dark
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars =
            true

        window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

i do this for my app inside onCreate

```
with(window) {
        setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
        )
    }
```

it works for me, and i hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved similar result by following approach.

```
    <style name="Theme.WebImageDownloader" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
     
    // make status bar icons colour grey
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    // override the notch area
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
    // make status bar transparent
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    // make navigation are transparent
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
   </style>
```

And set above theme in the manifest

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.WebImageDownloader">
```

Further more, i have placed my tool bar in the activity as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

// other views 

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="32dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

There 'ToolBarStyle', you can have any colour for background , text etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but isn't what I asked for

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun setStatusBar() {
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION
        )
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        window.navigationBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After days of searching, and literally have read all stackoverflow related posts. I hit to this below settings which worked for me. As I just played around and suddenly ran into it, so I have no idea why it worked.

SDK :
minSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 30

So, most of the suggestions were using deprecated APIs and most likely like this :

```html
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

And what i got with those settings:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbvBY.png)

Then it came to that grey status bar which i saw many people, same as me, wanted to get rid of it.

```html
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
```

I disabled that translucentStatus, and handle the display behind status bar using code :

```html
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyApp);
        getWindow().setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
```

I got this result after that :
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQIGl.png)

Lastly, we change the status bar text color:

```html
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

And it works:
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKFYf.png)

:)

Answer (score 0):

For who used a whole day to find how to make the status bar completely transparent.

**Firstly, remove the code like those:**
as my personal opinion, those setting is easily to mess up everything.

### This one will make the spinner inside scrollview not working.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

---

```
 View.setSystemUiVisibility()
```

---

```
 final View decorView = window.getDecorView();
 decorView.setSystemUiVisibility();
```

---

**After you clean up the code that you tried before.**

Add this into the activity OnCreated method.

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);
```

And add this into your theme file, base on you want to make navigation bar or status bar transparent

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>-->
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Add this if you need to setup the status bar with darker text color

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge

Answer (score -1):

I have tried all answers with different android versions.. and what worked with me:

- Don't set the android:windowTranslucentStatus as true, it will make a transparent status bar but with dark shadow.

```
// no need to add this.. it is false in default
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
```

- call this method in your activity to make the status bar transparent even for android 11 and 12

```
public void transparentStatusBar() {
        Window window = getWindow();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
        } else {
            window.setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
            );
        }
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

- If you found the navigation bar overlays the bottom views.. Just add padding at the bottom and avoid this :)
- To set the status bar tint black

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="M">true</item>
```

Comment: "Just add padding at the bottom" isn't an easy task. Some device have a bottom notch, some others don;t even have a soft navigation bar and still return a height for it. This whole thing is a total mess.

Comment: Just add padding at the bottom and avoid this, that is just really bad