# Make Android Notification Bar Transparent Not Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: java, android

How To Make Android Notification Bar Transparent Not Bottom Navigation Bar

**What I Want To Do**

```
Set Notification Bar - Transparent

Set Bottom Navigation Bar - Black
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in `<style>` tag of your app theme or activity theme under `theme.xml` file

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
```

Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your parent view of layout