# AdjustResize does work on Android 10 but not on 11 or 12

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to move my layout whenever the keyboard appears.

The development device is a xiaomi mi 9 lite running miui 12.0.10 and Android 10 QKQ1.

1. On my development device everything works as I expect it to work.
2. On the emulator (Pixel 3 API 30, Android 11) it does not work
3. On a Xiaomi Mi 11 Lite (MIUI12.5.6, Android 11 RKQ1) it does not work

This is my manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

This is my BaseTheme

```
<style name="App.Theme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

This is the skeleton of (one of the UI that does not scroll):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>  
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    <EditText>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I think the culprit is this code but I don't know how to fix this issue. This comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69688568/switch-status-bar-text-color-setappearancelightstatusbars-of-windowcontroller/69698725#69698725)

```
private void makeTransparentStatusBar() {
    Window window = getWindow();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 29) {
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
    } else {
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        // Making status bar overlaps with the activity
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false);
        //This sadly also overlapps the bottom navigation bar (which we do not want). Fix this
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(b.getRoot(), (v, windowInsets) -> {
            Insets insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());

            // Apply the insets as a margin to the view. Here the system is setting
            // only the bottom, left, and right dimensions, but apply whichever insets are
            // appropriate to your layout. You can also update the view padding
            // if that's more appropriate.
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) b.getRoot().getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(params.leftMargin, params.topMargin, params.rightMargin, insets.bottom);
            b.getRoot().setLayoutParams(params);

            // Return CONSUMED if you don't want want the window insets to keep being
            // passed down to descendant views.
            return WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the solution myself. There was a Bug in the Android 10+ API that prevented the Window to layout properly. Thats why above I had a workaround. It turns out the workaround is not needed anymore. The API 29 solution now works on 10 as well.