# Did split screen (multi window) change status bar behavior with Android 11

Tags: android, android-11, multi-window, split-screen

I've been building an [instrument cluster app](https://github.com/osunick/candash) that supports multi window (so you can split screen with navigation or media). For Android 6-10 I have no issues by making the following changes upon entering splitscreen mode:

```
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                        window?.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
                        window?.insetsController?.systemBarsBehavior =
                            WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
                        val wm = activity?.windowManager

                        wm?.removeViewImmediate(window?.getDecorView());
                        wm?.addView(window?.getDecorView(), window?.getAttributes());
                    }
```

However in Android 11+ instead of having a transparent status bar in split screen with the UI for my app rendering behind it, I get a white bar:

[Android 11 white bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD1J3.png)

How it works on 8-10:
[works properly on 8-10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi93A.png)

I'm stumped here, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question is misleading as the issue is the status bar with Android 11, and doesn't look to be specific to multi window

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68492550/230825) may contain the solution.