# How to make Status Bar fully transparent in .NET MAUI VISUAL STUDIOS 2022

Tags: c#, android, android-actionbar, statusbar, maui

So I was able to find that you can use depricated code to make the status bar on Android fully transparent:

```
    var s = SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen | SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable;
    FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content).SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)s;
    Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController = new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(Window, Window.DecorView);
    windowInsetsController.AppearanceLightStatusBars = true;
```

Since this code is deprecated, how do I achieve the same effect of the top status bar being fully transparent, as matching the background color of whatever picture or color is on the screen at the time. I am using .NET MAUI in VS 2022.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/68451704/199364. I won't mark this question as duplicate, because it would be great if you (or anyone) take one of those java answers, and rewrite it in c#. If you get it working, please add it as "Your Answer" below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code that should be on the page:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
#if ANDROID
    MainActivity.SetStatusBarLight(false);
#endif
}
```

Code in MainActivity.cs

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

    var s = SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen | SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable;
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
    FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content).SystemUiVisibility = 
    (StatusBarVisibility)s;
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
    Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController = new 
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(Window, Window.DecorView);
    windowInsetsController.AppearanceLightStatusBars = false;

    MainActivityInstance = this;
}

    public static void SetStatusBarLight(bool isLight)
{
    if (MainActivityInstance != null)
    {
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController =
        new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(MainActivityInstance.Window, MainActivityInstance.Window.DecorView);
        windowInsetsController.AppearanceLightStatusBars = isLight;
    }
}
```