# .NET MAUI Transparent Status Bar

Tags: c#, android, maui, .net-maui

How do I make the status bar transparent and show the content behind it on Android using .NET MAUI?

I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68451704/transparent-status-bar-with-visible-navigation-bar), is there a way to recreate this using C#?

Similar to Google Maps:
[image]

Comment: This issue can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394044/how-to-make-status-bar-fully-transparent-in-net-maui-visual-studios-2022

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this , in **MauiProgram.cs**

```
    .ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
            {
#if ANDROID
                events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnCreate((activity, bundle) => MakeStatusBarTranslucent(activity)));

                static void MakeStatusBarTranslucent(Android.App.Activity activity)
                {
                    activity.Window.SetFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits, Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);

                    activity.Window.ClearFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);

                    activity.Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                }
#endif
            });
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Install version 1.3.0+ of [CommunityToolkit.Maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/get-started), Gerald also has a video about it on [YT:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWj0PdImH10&ab_channel=GeraldVersluis)

And then in your ContentPage do something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Behaviors;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
             x:Class="MauiToolkitStatusBarBehaviorSample.MainPage">

<Page.Behaviors>
    <mct:StatusBarBehavior StatusBarColor="Transparent" StatusBarStyle="LightContent" />
</Page.Behaviors>
```

For other pages, you might want to set it up again since this behaviour is somewhat global and might effect other pages.

Comment: Just FYI: The StatusBarBehavios is buggy and doesn't work properly when changing the device orientation and it also behaves strangely, when changing the background color between pages.

Comment: @ewerspej Is it? May be i will try to add a fix for it thanks :)

Comment: Yep, there is a bug filed for it already: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/637

Comment: that is already closed though

Comment: True, it's fixed in the meanwhile, but it's only coming with the next release

Comment: Did you solve the problem? It seems StatusBarColor="Transparent"  won't work with images as a background.