# Make Title Bar Transparent, Transparent ActionBar - Sample Design Included - Is it possible to have such a material design page

Tags: android, android-activity, material-design

I am looking to develop a profile screen for my app. I am using AppCompactActivity as I need my app to support in non-lollipop devices as well. I need to make the title bar transparent only for this particular activity screen in the app.I also want the actionbar to be transparent.

[Picture - Material Design Sample Profile Page with Transparent Title and Action Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqYyP.jpg)

Please see the sample picture above that I got my MaterialDesign site and it will be great someone can get me the code for developing a page like this. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using AppCompatActivity then you can directly do the following in your main/parent activity.

> `int  FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY` :   Flag for requesting an Action Bar
>   that overlays window content.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    setContentView(yourview)
}
```

And make sure you do  not set any background for the action bar.
Using `supportRequestWindowFeature` is a convenience for calling `getWindow().requestFeature().`

Comment: I have tried this and it is a working solution for making ActionBar transparent. However, 'AppCompatDelegate.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY' is the updated solution.

I am still not able to make the status bar transparent. Is there any similar method, that you applied to actionbar, available for title bar as well? Please refer the image.

Comment: @sreeragnk  have you tried what is suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent

Comment: The problem is I am using  minSdkVersion 16.

Answer (score 0):

You can style for this

```
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
       <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Or if programmatically you can use

```
    actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
```

Hope it helps. I prefer style :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use hex color:

```
 actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("#00343434"))
```

#**00**343434 first 2 number describes its transparency.

- 00 --> %100 transparent
- ..
- ..
- FF --> no transparent

[look for detail about transparent codes;](https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4)