# Android draw behind status bar

Tags: android, statusbar, transparent

I am trying to get a completely transparent (NOT translucent) status bar in Android 5.0+. While landscape work fine with the image occupying the whole screen, except the navigation bar, portrait sets the status bar color to app_main_accent (the same as image background) and the image occupies the rest of the screen. I am using the same layout file for both portrait and landscape and the results are different. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project with the same result. Please help me get it working. Thank you.

Support library version: 23.3.0

my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ActivityDetails2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransparentTitleBar"
        >
    </activity>
```

then v21/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TransparentTitleBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

activity:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.jgarin.R;
import com.jgarin.core.db.DBElements.BaseGroupElement;

public class ActivityDetails2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String ITEM_KEY = "itemKey";

    private BaseGroupElement item;

    public static Intent getLaunchIntent(final Context context, final BaseGroupElement item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityDetails2.class);
        intent.putExtra(ITEM_KEY, (Parcelable) item);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details2);

        item = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(ITEM_KEY);
    }
}
```

and layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/app_main_accent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/material_flat"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            >
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent)

Comment: i have just tried #1 with no change. it's still the same