# Need fully transparent status bar

Tags: android, android-studio, statusbar, transparent

Hi Friends I want to know can I change status bar color or make it completely transparent.

I've tried so many things but I can't get the fully transparent status bar, so here is my code..

**v21/style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

        style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

            <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
            <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        </style>
</resources>
```

and **style.xml**

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

after it my screen is displayed as...
[image: current login screen]

and I want it like this..

[image: desired login screen]

can anyone help?Thanks.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

try this hex code transperency:

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

Comment: where I put this hex code? because I don't know anything about hex code.

Comment: put it here <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>          put  #00ffffff  try another transpernacy

Comment: Thanks @Damini Mehra

Comment: I just remove this line from my v21/style.exe  <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>  and try your code its working with this its isn't working  thanks a lot

Answer (score 14):

I know its late to ans this question but this is what helped me and may help future visitors..

```
// transparent statusbar for marshmallow and above
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (yourView != null) {
            yourView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
        }
    }

    //make full transparent statusBar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, true);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

 public static void setWindowFlag(Activity activity, final int bits, boolean on) {
    Window win = activity.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
    if (on) {
        winParams.flags |= bits;
    } else {
        winParams.flags &= ~bits;
    }
    win.setAttributes(winParams);
}
```

Comment: What is your `yourView` referring to here? RootView?

Comment: @fahmy did u get it or need some help?

Comment: yes please, still would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write all these stuff, just add in your kotlin activity

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

and in your theme

```
<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
```