# Transparent action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-styles

I had to develop transparent action bar.
After some research I was able to achieve the desired result only on LG2 device.
When i run the code on LG3 it's not working (action bar not transperent).

That's how my style folder looks:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

  </resources>
```

Someone has a suggestion  how to solve this issue ?

Comment: check this ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019028/need-fully-transparent-status-bar/37019100#37019100 @sollo

Comment: @DaminiMehra tnx for the reference. i I solved my problem with the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to define style having no `actionbar`. Use toolbar and set its color transparent.

```
<!-- Your App Theme -->

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        </style>

<!-- Your custom ActionBar Style -->

<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Your `

> toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"/>
```

Use this `toolbar` in any layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Toolbar should be above content-->
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`

Comment: Hi,sorry for my late reply. its helped me a lot.tnx