# How to change the color for the status bar for lollipop devices?

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I am facing the issue in changing the colour of the status bar in lollipop devices .

Intially my status bar colour is in light grey i want to change the status bar colour into red. [image]

The styles using for the activity is

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#A82A37</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

The above style added in my application but there is no change in status bar colour.Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341818/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-status-bar-in-android

Comment: @ quick learner I searched but i can;t solve it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42783789/7538260 Try this...

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
public static void changeStatusBarColor(Activity act, int colorRes) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        act.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        act.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        act.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(act, colorRes));
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to add the style in my application,if i add code means i want to repeat in all activity

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder under /res called /values-v21 and put this styles.xml in there.

Comment: I applied the theme in application

Comment: Is your style in values-v21/styles.xml?

Comment: no, i didn't created like that

Comment: OK it needs to be in values-v21

Comment: how can i create the values-v21

Comment: I updated my answer