# Statusbar is not transparent but white

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, kotlin, anko

To test kotlin with anko DSL I decided to start a new proyect in last android studio ide (2.1.3), using kotlin plugin (1.0.3) and latest anko library (0.9)

I used the default proyect Navigation Drawer Activity, so I just had to convert the main xml to anko.

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

            <TextView
                android:text="Hello World!"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And it is working perfectly, as you can see here:
[image: [xml]]

With anko, I tried to copy every detail from the xml, getting this code:

```
class MainActivityUi: AnkoComponent<MainActivity> {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MainActivity>) = with(ui) {

        drawerLayout {
            id = R.id.drawer_layout
            fitsSystemWindows = true

            coordinatorLayout {

                appBarLayout(R.style.AppTheme_AppBarOverlay) {

                    toolbar {
                        id = R.id.toolbar
                        backgroundColor = colorAttr(R.attr.colorPrimary)
                        popupTheme = R.style.AppTheme_PopupOverlay
                    }.lparams(height=dimenAttr(R.attr.actionBarSize),width=matchParent)

                }.lparams(width=matchParent)

                relativeLayout {
                    padding = dip(16)

                    textView("Hello World!")

                }.lparams(height=matchParent,width=matchParent) {
                   behavior = AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior()
                }

            }.lparams(height=matchParent,width=matchParent)

            navigationView {
                id = R.id.nav_view
                inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main)
                inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer)

            }.lparams(height=matchParent) {
                gravity = Gravity.START
                fitsSystemWindows = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And instead, I'm getting this white statusbar: [image: anko]

The only changes I did was in the MainActivity change the setContentView(R.layout.activity_main), to MainActivityUi.setContentView(this).

So, my question is, why is this happening when they are the same views and layouts? and how can I fix that?

EDIT: I'm using the default proyect that it's created when in Android Studio you choose new proyect, and then you choose DrawerNavigationActivity. If in setContentView I choose to show the xml's view, the statusbar is blue (first screenshot), but if I choose to show the anko's view I get the white statusbar.

In both cases, I'm using same themes, colors, etc, and when using the xml layout, everything is working perfectly, so it must be an anko's problem

Comment: have you tried to set fitsSystemWindows = true to appBarLayout?

Comment: Exactly the same problem here, I put just a `Drawer`, the status bar had a white background out there. idk, but with xml it works quite fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do

`window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)`

inside onCreate()

it worked for me

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent)

EDIT:
Also My Code

```
drawerLayout {
  lparams(width = matchParent, height = matchParent)

  coordinatorLayout {
     setPadding(0, dip(24), 0, 0)

     appBarLayout {
        toolbar {
           backgroundColor = primaryColor
           setTitleTextColor(primaryColorText)
        }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = dip(toolbar_size))

     }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = dip(toolbar_size))

  }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = matchParent)

  navigationView {

  }.lparams(width = dip(302), height = matchParent) {
     gravity = Gravity.START
  }
}
```

EDIT 2:
By looking at the [source code of androidx](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/drawerlayout/drawerlayout/src/main/java/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout.java#L372), they add some code to handle "fitsSystemWindows". We can copy and paste to archive the same effect. Although Anko is dead, it still useful to create Drawerlayout programmatically (and with any other DSL library)

```
if (ViewCompat.getFitsSystemWindows(this)) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
            @Override
            public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View view, WindowInsets insets) {
                final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view;
                drawerLayout.setChildInsets(insets, insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop() > 0);
                return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
            }
        });
        setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(THEME_ATTRS);
        try {
            mStatusBarBackground = a.getDrawable(0);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    } else {
        mStatusBarBackground = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong thinking that the status bar is `transparent` by default.

According to this image

[image]

taken from Android Developers Reference. Check: https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

the status bar color depends on what you have defined in `colors.xml` or `styles.xml` in `values` folder as `colorPrimaryDark`, so it's not transparent.

Your problem is not `white` color in status bar which is correct for transparency, but not enough knowledge of using themes in Android applications.

**EDIT:** Changing status bar color (Java):

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();

// clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

// add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

// finally change the color
window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.my_statusbar_color));
```

or

```
 public void setStatusBarColor(View statusBar,int color){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
           Window w = getWindow();
           w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
           //status bar height
           int actionBarHeight = getActionBarHeight();
           int statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight();
           //action bar height
           statusBar.getLayoutParams().height = actionBarHeight + statusBarHeight;
           statusBar.setBackgroundColor(color);
     }
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: I don't really think themes are the problem, as I have I'm using the default example proyect "Navigation Drawer Activity" from Android Studio's new proyect. If I compile the app, with setContentView(R.layout.activity_main), it load's the xml's view (the first screenshot I did), and, if instead of that, I set MainActivityUi().setContentView(this), the anko's view is loaded, and it shows like the second picture I did, so theme seems to be fine

Comment: I've edit my question too, thanks for the help anyways, but transparency is working fine with the xml, so the problem has to be anko's DSL related

Comment: nope, that's not problem with anko. Write the same in java and you would find the same effect. Anko was made to ommit `xml` files due to increase the app performance

Comment: exactly, that's the anko point, so how do you explain that with the xml's layout the transparency is working fine and with the anko's one isn't? It should be the same

Comment: i don't see in your code changing status bar color. I only see changing color of toolbar

Comment: Yeah now I understand what are you talking about. Let me explain, my statusbar color is set to transparent in styles, so when you use the xml layout, the statusbar takes the color of the toolbar, but, when I use anko, it doesn't, and it shows the white, so there must be some problem in my anko layout as the statusbar is taking the color of some element that it's not the toolbar, and this is what I don't understand, as my anko's layout is just the same as the xml's one

Answer (score 0):

It is not your statusbar color issue. 
Correct me if I am wrong, I believe you are using the **Cyanogenmod OS 13.0 edition** by the looks of your battery symbol. Switch it back to the default theme in your themes section. Then report back if the issue still persists with your `colors.xml` file.

Refer this link here for your Kotlin translucent status bar issue. 

https://github.com/fython/MaterialStatusBarCompat

Comment: See the edited answer for Kotlin plugin sample for status bar translucent issue.