# need to change status bar as transparent with all icons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design

In my android application, I need to change status bar as transparent with all icons. I do not want to change color or make it translucent.

I want status bar as shown in the image below :

```html
<style name="AppTheme.FullScreen" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Its duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lollipop : draw behind statusBar with its color set to transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transparent status bar using programatically like this
call this in **onCreate** method

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
```

Comment: it does status bar translucent. but i need to do status bar as transparent completely.