# Xamarin Shell windows full screen but show status bar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, fullscreen, statusbar, xamarin.shell

How i can create with xamarin shell (android and ios) the Google Map effect (show app in full screen but not hide the status bar). Thx.

[image: Google Map screen capture]

For Android i found:

In OnCreate method

```
Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits, WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);            
Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
```

But I still need to change the color of the icons?

No solution for iOS yet!

Answer (score 0):

**For Android:**

1.Change the style.xml

You can add the code into the Android styles.xml. This can make the status bar transparent.

```
<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

2.Adding method in MainActivity.cs.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
       ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
       base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

       Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
       global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

       if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
       {
           
           Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
           
           Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentNavigation);
       }

       LoadApplication(new App());
```

**For ios**
You can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/tabbedpage-translucent-tabbar) .

For more details about this question:

[Xamarin Forms Android transparent status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798519/xamarin-forms-android-transparent-status-bar)