# Custom Translucent Color (changing transparency)

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I am trying to achieve brighter translucent status bar ,only the status bar and trying to keep navigation bar as its default.

I tried some solutions(actually non of them worked as what i want).

In this one i couldn't change translucent transparency, i am trying to get brighter one.But it is not changing.
*http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx*

The other option, i tried to use fullscreen theme and placed a gradient view same height as status(that is what i want). But in this time Layout extends behind of navigation and navigation looses its black background.I couldn't find solution for that.(making it translucent not what i want)

TLDR : i am trying to get brighter translucent status with keeping navigation as its default. Is it possible?
Edit. min SDK is 20
(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent/28041425#28041425)
  By adding this one into onCreate()

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
   View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

And this adding this into your style

```
 <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possibile.

1. Set the translucent status

   ```
   <style name="AppThemeTranslucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
         <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
         <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Set a color for your status bar using:

   ```
   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
   private void setTrasparentStatusBar() {
   Window window = getWindow();
       window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
       window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

       window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.status_bar_color));

       window.setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.black));
   }
   ```
3. Add this property to you root layout

   ```
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   ```

And this is what I achieve with this code

[image: sample]

---

**EDIT**

I investigated about this feature, not all the view implement `fitsSystemWindows` so not always you can get this results.

I suggest you to read [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec) and here a [repo](https://github.com/appersiano/TranslucentStatusBarSample) with a sample using a `CoordinatorLayout` with a negative `marginTop`

Comment: Navigation stays translucent, if i remove translucency of navigation, it oddly remove status bar colour to white. I think navigation translucency overrides navigation colour

Comment: I forgot to tell you to add fitSystemWindows attribute, check the updated answer!

Comment: i think i have issue with my theme or layout. I need to figure out first. Thanks!!

Comment: i couldn't get black navigation sorry it still does same thing, either layout extends behind of navigation or status bar looses its transparency