# Transparent Status Bar and scrollable layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-statusbar

I have a layout with different TextViews, and I want that when the keyboard is visible, the layout will be scrollable.

I added to my Activity: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in the manifest.

and it worked.

Then, when I followed the below link for transparent status bar, the status bar was indeed transparent, but the layout was not scrollable

[Lollipop : draw behind statusBar with its color set to transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent)

Any idea how can I achieve both?

Thanks,

Comment: You could try putting your `TextViews` inside a `ScrollView` in your XML layout.

Comment: I have a scrollview, it doesn't work with this setting