# How to implement the Toolbar and Status bar of Google play store app in my app?

Tags: android, toolbar, statusbar

If you go into the Google Play store, and open the details page for an app, the banner image is visible even up to behind the status bar. How do I  implement the same effect in my app (an image going up into the status bar)?

I have tried the following layout XML code in my app, but it doesn't make the status bar completely transparent:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question I think is essentially the same as this one: [Lollipop : draw behind statusBar with its color set to transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent) and there are some good answers there.