# 100% transparent status bar android in lollipop

Tags: android, statusbar, transparent

I want to make 100% translucent status bar in android so that it should show the image below it clearly. Image Attached.

I have set the following theme to my activity :

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppThemeT" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

But it is giving a weird gray colored shadow on the top. check attached image. I want to remove that shadow.
[image]

Comment: have a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent) if you already not .

Comment: @ADM Already done. No change

Comment: can you post the color code of `@color/transparent`

Comment: @KapilRajput     <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>

Comment: window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

Answer (score 3):

apply this theme to your layout root

```
<style name="AppTheme.Transparent">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

And this back in your java activity file:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
```

Comment: Have you yourself tested it ? This will not even make the status bar transparent. It will also give that weird gray shadow over it

Comment: it worked for me. on android 9, there was a gray shadow, but after set flags, it disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your `onCreate();`

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Immersive view to remove that.
You can [learn form here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your styles.xml, you add below lines.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

create `styles.xml` for v21 and it should look like below:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
   <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
   <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and in your `manifest` file you need to define your application theme:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

also you need to define activity theme in your `manifest` file

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```