# Draw behind status bar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have defined a `relativeLayout` with a `recyclerView` and an `imageView`. I want the `imageView` to draw behind the status bar. But for some reason

```
android:fitsSystemWindow = true
```

doesn't work.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lollipop : draw behind statusBar with its color set to transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent)

Answer (score 2):

Set your full-screen theme like following

```
  <style name="Theme.MyApp.FullScreen" parent="Theme.MyApp">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>   
 </style>
```

Don't add **android:fitsSystemWindows="true"** in your layout file

Also, no need to add **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** in Manifest file

Answer (score 1):

To draw behind status bar, You have to set your status bar have transparent background.

So, you need to set this with **adding below proprieties** in your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

And **in your .xml** you have already set below property which is useful:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```