# Draw view under status bar but not under the navigation bar

Tags: android

Is there a way to draw under the status bar but not the navigation bar?

Currently I am using `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);` but it also draws under the navigation bar aswell as the status bar.

I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent/28041425#28041425) but it doesn't allow me to draw under the status bar.

This is my activity_main.xml if it helps. I am putting my fragments in the container frame layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:padding="11dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:padding="11dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:padding="11dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:padding="11dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```